# qbasic version of PHP serialize/unserialize

Tags: php, serialization, qbasic

I can't find this anywhere. I have some old basic programs I am working on (thanks to qb64 that came out, now they work on winxp - win7)
in order to serialize (like php) I need to know how this process works so that i can convert BASIC do it. it does not have to be fancy, but I would like to get an understanding how it works.

I like the way php does it, although since BASIC can not do 'associative" arrays, i would think it is much easier.

so in simple terms, is there a source for serialize/unserialize ?

Comment: one more desperate look and found this: http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize:508 - little more complex than I wanted.. i'll have to see what i can do from scratch - open to ideas :-)

Comment: Are you saying you want to de-/serialize **PHP strings** in BASIC, or that you want a de-/serialization function that works in BASIC on BASIC, just *like PHP*? I.e. will it have to be compatible with PHP's `serialize`, or are you just looking for *any* serialization functionality in BASIC?

Comment: @deceze - BASIC equivalent of PHP's function de/serialize (but in qbasic, **not vb basic**. because vb basic can do a little more than qb. and I am working in qb. - don't ask LOL) and yes - **ANY** serilization will work as long as i can turn it into a string and back. i find the serialized arrays are excellent for small databases

Answer (score 0):

looks like you'd serialize it with simple string concatenation. Use something like "||" as your seperator. Since there are no associative arrays, you don't have to worry about names, just value.

Then you'd use instr() and left$() or mid$() to split them back out.

For multidimensional arrays, it would be considerably more complex and I haven't given it the time to figure  out exactly how I'd do  it, but I thought about using seperatators like ||0|0|| for array(0,0) and ||0|1|| for array(0,1) or even ||0|1|1|| for array (0,1,1)

Comment: If I were less rusty, I'd have written the code, but I haven't touched QBasic in several years, until tonite.